# PyGears hdlgen not generating DTI definition files

Tags: python, pygears

This is my code

```
from pygears import gear
from pygears.typing import Fixp, Tuple
from pygears.lib import add, qround, saturate, drv, collect
from pygears.sim import sim
from pygears.hdl import hdlgen

@gear
def adder(data: Tuple[Fixp[10, 32], Fixp[10, 32]]):
  return add(data[0],data[1]) \
    | qround (fract=21) \
    | saturate(t=Fixp[11, 32])

hdlgen('/adder',outdir='./Example1/adder_hdl')
```

Generated files don't include any file that is defining the DTI interface. Am I missing something or what?

Answer (score 0):

By default PyGears is not including these files because it's possible that you already have them generated. If that is not the case **copy_files** parameter should be set to **true**

> The function **hdlgen** supports the following parameters:
>
> - **top** - Path to the module (within the design hierarchy) that should be generated. PyGears uses POSIX like paths, i.e.
>   '/path/to/my/module`
> - **lang** - HDL language to use. SystemVerilog: 'sv' and Verilog: 'v' currently supported
> - **outdir** - Directory where to place the generated files
> - **copy_files** - When set to True it will also copy needed files from PyGears library to outdir. When set to False, you will have to
>   make sure to include the PyGears libraries also when using the
>   generated files.